# Why like query in mysql is using both index and where condition?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with huge amount of data. I am performing prefix search for one column with this table and this query is always getting listed in slow queries in the logs.

We already have a multicolumn index for all the columns that are present in the where clause in the query with a partial index for column having like operator in query.

**Sample Table Script**:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_query` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_col_one` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `test_column_two` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_column_three` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8,
  KEY `two_three_one` (`test_col_one`,`test_column_three`(12),`test_column_two`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Sample Query**:

```
select id, hex(uuid), code , hex(test_col_one), test_column_two, test_column_three  from test_query where test_column_two=0 and test_col_one = UNHEX('AE7C96BF7972453F8F2B09CD8B50B515') and test_column_three LIKE 'abc%';
```

**Explain Output**:

```
id |select_type |table      |partitions |type  |possible_keys |key           |key_len |ref |rows |filtered |Extra                              |
---|------------|-----------|-----------|------|--------------|--------------|--------|----|-----|---------|-----------------------------------|

1  |SIMPLE      |test_query |           |range |two_three_one |two_three_one |57      |    |1    |100      |Using index condition; Using where |
```

Besides having index on all the three columns, it still shows, using where in Extra for EXPLAIN query. I believe this is what is making this query.
Kindly suggest why this query cannot be executed using index alone or if there is some other possible reason which is making this query slow and how can performance be optimised for this query.

As the table is already holding huge data, creating new index is difficult and need some solution with the query itself.

Comment: A query describes what you want to get. Indexes help to get it faster. Your query is so simple that there is no other (reasonable) way to write it, so the only way to change execution time is to change your indexes. But unless you have only a *really* small number of rows that have `test_column_two = 0` and *a lot* of rows that start with `abc%`, `Using index condition;` should have zero impact on your execution time for this query though. What is your execution time anyway? How many rows do you get? Does removing `code` from the select list change execution time?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the columns in the index matters.

Try to change the key to:

```
KEY `two_three_one` (`test_col_one`,`test_column_two`,`test_column_three`(12))
```

Comment: Why would the order of the columns in the index matter for this specific query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Because `test_column_three LIKE 'abc%'` is a range scan. So no column in the index comming after `test_column_three` can be used efficiently. For the given query it should be the last column in the index.